# facebook links in RSS

Tags: php, hyperlink, rss

I am trying to extract the PHP of links generated in a facebook RSS feed, and make it into simple html once clicked. the links look like this:

```
http://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.theguardian.com%2Ftravel%2F2014%2Fapr%2F25%2Fitaly-puglia-salento-region&h=2AQF4oNrg&s=1
```

this is the original link:

```
http://www.theguardian.com/travel/2014/apr/25/italy-puglia-salento-region
```

I am using this code but seems to be an error on line 2.

```
$matches = array();
pregmatchall(/http:\/\/l\.facebook\.com\/l\.php\?u=([^"]+)/, $rss, $matches);

foreach($matches[0] as $index => $match) {
    $url = urldecode(html_entity_decode($matches[1][$index]));
    str_replace($match, $url, $rss);
}
```

Comment: Does that seemingly error come with an associated error message?

Comment: you have an syntax error `pregmatchall` => `preg_match_all`

Comment: @Vijayaragavendran tried the underscore but still giving an error:  PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/', expecting ')' in your code on line 2. i chechked the code on http://phpcodechecker.com/

Comment: why not use `parse_url` instead, your objective is just to get the value of `?u=` anyway

Comment: try this `preg_match_all('/http:\/\/l\.facebook\.com\/l\.php\?u=([^"]+)/', $rss, $matches);`

Comment: @kevinabelita thanks for your reply, but am not strong with php..could help with that please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$matches = array();
$rss="http://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.theguardian.com%2Ftravel%2F2014%2Fapr%2F25%2Fitaly-puglia-salento-region&h=2AQF4oNrg&s=1";
preg_match_all('/http:\/\/l\.facebook\.com\/l\.php\?u=([^"]+)/', $rss, $matches);

foreach($matches[0] as $index => $match) {
    $url = urldecode(html_entity_decode($matches[1][$index]));
    str_replace($match, $url, $rss);
}

echo $url;
```

Comment: tried this one but once clicked the php appear again, also it works for just that particular link

Comment: then you have to rewrite the preg match

Comment: not sure on how to do that. anyway if i hover the output i can see the php coming again

Comment: this is what is going on in the dom _onclick="LinkshimAsyncLink.swap(this, " http:\="" \="" l.facebook.com\="" l.php?u=etcetc